# Knockout Complex Data Model Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Let's start with the code..

Javascript to bind viewmodel and display dialog

```
$("#add-song").click(function () {
    $("<div>")
        .attr("data-bind", "template: { name: 'manage-song-template' }")
        .dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Add Song",
            width: 960,
            height: 490,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Create Song",
                    'data-bind': 'click: savechanges',
                    click: function () {

                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Close",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
            close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            },
            open: function () {
                ko.applyBindings(new my.managesongviewmodel());
                jquerybindings();
            }
        });        
});
```

Now let's take a look at the view model

```
my.managesongviewmodel = function () {
    var
        //Scalar Properties
        song = null,

        //Functions
        loadfromserver = function (Id) {
            $.post("/song/getsong", "id=1", function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    var data = response.Data;
                    var song = response.Data.Song;

                    var songdata = {
                        Song: {
                            Id: song.Id,
                            Title: song.Title,
                            Description: song.Description,
                            Lyrics: song.Lyrics,
                            isMaster: song.isMaster,
                            AudioFilePath: song.AudioFilePath,
                            CoverImageFilePath: song.CoverImageFilePath,
                            CreatedDate: song.CreatedDate
                        },
                        Genres: data.Genres,
                        SongAlternateTitles: data.SongAlternateTitles,
                        Exploitations: data.Exploitations,
                        SongWriterSongs: data.SongWriterSongs
                    };                        
                    song = new my.song(songdata);
                    alert(song.title());
                }
            });
        },

        savechanges = function () {
        };

    loadfromserver();
    return {
        song: song,
        loadfromserver: loadfromserver
    };
};

my.song = function (data) {
    var
        //Scalar Properties
        id = ko.observable(data.Song.Id),
        title = ko.observable(data.Song.Title),
        description = ko.observable(data.Song.Description),
        lyrics = ko.observable(data.Song.Lyrics),
        ismaster = ko.observable(data.Song.isMaster),
        audiofilepath = ko.observable(data.Song.AudioFilePath),
        coverimagefilepath = ko.observable(data.Song.CoverImageFilePath),
        createddate = ko.observable(data.Song.CreatedDate),

        //Arrays
        genres = ko.observableArray(data.Genres),
        alttitles = ko.observableArray(data.SongAlternateTitles),
        exploitations = ko.observableArray(data.Exploitations),
        songwritersongs = ko.observableArray(data.SongWriterSongs);

    return {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        description: description,
        lyrics: lyrics,
        ismaster: ismaster,
        audiofilepath: audiofilepath,
        coverimagefilepath: coverimagefilepath,
        createddate: createddate,

        genres: genres,
        alttitles: alttitles,
        exploitations: exploitations,
        songwritersongs: songwritersongs
    };
};
```

Here is my template

```
<script type="text/html" id="manage-song-template">
    <div class="modal-form">
        <span data-bind="text: song.title"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Chrome is throwing the error "Cannot read property 'title' of null;" when I launch the dialog.  That said, the "alert(song.title());" actually shows a the song title.

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

## Update

I have created a jsfiddle that replicates the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/mcottingham/H7jqa/28/

Comment: This isn't working because the bindings happen before the AJAX call is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. In the moment when you shows modal window your song var still equals `null`. So you have to wait while info about song will be loaded from server:

```
$("<div>").attr("data-bind", "template: { name: 'manage-song-template' }").dialog({
   // another options
   open: function (event, ui) {
     var vm = new my.managesongviewmodel(), domNode = this;
     vm.loadfromserver().done(function() {
       ko.applyBindings(vm, domNode);
       jquerybindings();
     });
   }
})
```

// another code

And add `return` statement at the begining of `loadfromserver` function:

```
loadfromserver = function (Id) {
   return $.post("/song/getsong", "id=1", function (response) {
    // code
   });
}
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was typing. +1 for proper handling of the jqxhr object.

Comment: Also as the code improvment you can replace `ko.applyBindings(vm, domNode)` with `ko.applyBindingsToNode(domNode, { template: { name: 'manage-song-template' } })`. Then you can also remove call of `attr('data-bind', ...)` method. This change makes your code faster and more elegant

Comment: @Serjio I've made the modification suggested, however, I am still getting the same error.  The alert is still showing the title text.

Comment: @mcottingham can you give me a url of jsfiddle, etc?

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcottingham/H7jqa/10/  I've never made one before so I'm not 100% sure that I've done it correctly.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @mcottingham Yes, you are right. There is also another error with not proper usage of closure. Your viewmodel looked a bit complicated for me, so I decided to re-factor it. You can find working result at http://jsfiddle.net/DaFNL/1/

Comment: @Serjio Thank You!  I've been staring at this for 3 days and have not been able to find the issue.  Where was my issue with closure?

Comment: @mcottingham in your source code you defined `song` variable twice: once - in scope of `my.managesongviewmodel` function and second - in scope of ajax callback function. So, when you assign new instance of `my.song` pseudo-class it was assigned to local `song` var and not to `song` var of your view model. So, when I suggested my solution with `vm.loadfromserver().done` there was still error with that local `song` var inside `$.post(...,..., function () { var song = ..}`

Comment: @Serjio ah, ok.  I guess that I wasn't thinking that the 'song' of my.managesongviewmodel would be in scope of the callback function.  I guess it is sort of obvious now that you mention it.  Thank you!